# Scaling dynos... Couldn't find that process type (web)

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, deployment

He desplegado [una API](https://github.com/antoinecomp/PerfumeRecommender-API) que funciona muy bien a nivel local.
Pero a pesar de que está marcado como "DEPLOYED" obtengo los siguientes errores cuando intento ejecutar una solicitud como

```
https://perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com/perfume?features=elegant
```

Obtengo:

```
2021-06-27T21:17:53.813080+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-06-27T21:17:53.813080+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-06-27T21:17:53.813081+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2021-06-27T21:17:53.813232+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-27 21:17:53 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-06-27T21:17:53.841222+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-27 21:17:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-06-27T21:17:53.841289+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-27 21:17:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-06-27T21:17:53.920263+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-06-27T21:17:53.976556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-27T21:30:30.353094+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=04001169-d56f-406f-ad1c-d2ab1000ab06 fwd="109.190.253.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T21:30:30.959960+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=cf22c89b-8085-4917-8278-8753bc46485b fwd="109.190.253.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T21:30:50.448657+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=f24ce971-1ac7-4982-ac5f-8de9095fa04d fwd="109.190.253.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T21:30:50.978280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=8cd815c4-27e6-4f83-abd1-d3d35b0b308e fwd="109.190.253.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T21:32:09.187154+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user antoine.compagnie@gmail.com
2021-06-27T21:32:15.031431+00:00 heroku[run.2803]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-27T21:32:14.998605+00:00 heroku[run.2803]: Awaiting client
2021-06-27T21:32:15.286888+00:00 heroku[run.2803]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2021-06-27T21:32:19.772364+00:00 heroku[run.2803]: Process exited with status 127
2021-06-27T21:32:19.890495+00:00 heroku[run.2803]: State changed from up to complete
2021-06-27T21:37:31.076435+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python console` by user antoine.compagnie@gmail.com
2021-06-27T21:37:36.598651+00:00 heroku[run.1177]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-27T21:37:36.591905+00:00 heroku[run.1177]: Awaiting client
2021-06-27T21:37:36.883530+00:00 heroku[run.1177]: Starting process with command `python console`
2021-06-27T21:37:41.432297+00:00 heroku[run.1177]: Process exited with status 2
2021-06-27T21:37:41.491031+00:00 heroku[run.1177]: State changed from up to complete
2021-06-27T21:38:27.723793+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py shell` by user antoine.compagnie@gmail.com
2021-06-27T21:38:34.644820+00:00 heroku[run.5084]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-27T21:38:35.010670+00:00 heroku[run.5084]: Awaiting client
2021-06-27T21:38:35.328461+00:00 heroku[run.5084]: Starting process with command `python manage.py shell`
2021-06-27T21:38:40.092046+00:00 heroku[run.5084]: Process exited with status 2
2021-06-27T21:38:40.154155+00:00 heroku[run.5084]: State changed from up to complete
2021-06-27T21:40:02.792123+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=a22d1db4-e506-4ff7-bf24-b3b304836065 fwd="109.190.253.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T21:40:04.026669+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=20b33104-4639-496a-9dcd-ae52e5745c01 fwd="109.190.253.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T21:40:08.988643+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=503c72fd-4a29-4b62-aac7-385daef1d6b5 fwd="109.190.253.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T21:40:09.465421+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=92e8f4f1-bcda-4c69-a404-e7d7ffe170b0 fwd="109.190.253.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T21:42:42.725386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=5c6e81a2-b1db-4b37-8236-019976bdaaf5 fwd="109.190.253.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-27T21:42:43.269768+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=07c22ebc-e2ba-4571-b95f-00e5df445721 fwd="109.190.253.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Es posible que es a causa de los requirements?

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Flask-RESTful==0.3.7
gunicorn==20.0.4
joblib==0.13.2
jsonschema==2.6.0
pandas
pickleshare==0.7.5
requests==2.23.0
requests-file==1.4.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

He probado a escalar los bancos de potencia

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\API>heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free
```

Aqui esta el Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --max-requests 2
```

## cambiar Dynos

Intenté cambiar los dynos:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\API>heroku ps:scale web=2 worker=1
Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (worker).
```

Estoy usando el free tier

## Cambiar Procfile

He añadido y eliminado el Procfile (Y también hice un wsgi.py pero no sé para qué lo voy a usar) y ahora tengo:

```
2021-07-03T13:11:36.799997+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=perfumerecommender-a
pi.herokuapp.com request_id=25bc35a1-3e4d-4dd2-9a96-f167ba47e9df fwd="78.197.172.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Entonces hice:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\API>heroku buildpacks:clear
Buildpacks cleared. Next release on perfumerecommender-api will detect buildpacks normally.

(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\API>heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python
Buildpack added. Next release on perfumerecommender-api will use heroku/python.
Run git push heroku main to create a new release using this buildpack.

(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\API>git commit --allow-empty -m "Adjust buildpacks on Heroku"
[master 50d63ef] Adjust buildpacks on Heroku

(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\API>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 1, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 194 bytes | 194.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the same version as the last build: python-3.9.5
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.9.6
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Using cached install of python-3.9.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 85M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v12
remote:        https://perfumerecommender-api.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/perfumerecommender-api.git
   d88377d..50d63ef  master -> master
```

Y ahora obtengo:

```
2021-07-03T14:02:01.773792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=HEAD path="/perfume?features=elegant" host=perfum
erecommender-api.herokuapp.com request_id=59c6e4d3-5ff2-4e64-a513-522f20e4314a fwd="185.224.138.44" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
s
```

Comment: has configurado tu archivo `runtime`?

Comment: creo que eso era problema del `dyno` y tenia que ser cambiarlo mediante *heroku CLI*

Comment: No sérieux que es un runtime. Solo hice un procfile @Christian . Gracias para la ayuda, como puedo cambiar el  _dyno_ con Heroku CLI y que es esto ?

Comment: bueno existen 2 un runtime y procfile, pero no recuerdo cual se usaba para las apis. Espera busco la documentación a cerca del `dyno` y te la paso

Comment: Puedes ver [esto](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed) y creo que también te puede servir esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed) (En ingles) y creo que una solución seria [esto](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running) La documentación de heroku es buena, a mi me ayudo cuando tuve ese error

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Christian Por desgracia he probado todo y no parece cambiar cualquiera cosa ...

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿has visto si Heroku tiene limitaciones con free-tier o estás pagando por el servicio?

Comment: Hmmm, @fredyfx Estoy [este tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-movie-recommendation-api-using-scikit-learn-flask-and-heroku-bee239dc96e3) desplegando una API y no me pareció que la necesitaran. Además la babosa es de 50MB de los 500 ofrecidos

Comment: No le se, pero ese `max requests` lo veo un poco raro

Comment: Añadimos un `max requests` para asegurar que nuestro servidor se reinicie después de cada segunda petición a nuestra API, @Christian . Esto se hace para asegurar que no excedemos nuestro límite de RAM de 512 MB asignado por Heroku al usar la API.